# Why would the index on a field be a different size depending on if it is ascending or descending in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing, mongodb-query

I have two single indexes for the "created" field in my collection. One index is sorted ascending, and the other is sorted descending. The index that is sorted descending is larger than the index sorted ascending.  The created field holds a Javascript Date object. What would cause this?

```
"indexSizes" : {
    "_id_" : 212862160,
    "created_1" : 136424736,
    "created_-1" : 252376768
},
```

Here is the details from collection.getIndexes().  The only difference is the descending index was created in the background.

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "created" : 1
    },
    "name" : "created_1",
    "ns" : "Production.accounts"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "created" : -1
    },
    "name" : "created_-1",
    "ns" : "Production.accounts",
    "background" : true
}
```

Comment: Now that is a fair ask. Kind of wondering myself why the "ascending" form is lesser than the `_id` index in size. For the record, you might consider that `_id` if an `ObjectId` is already "monotonic" or "always increasing" and therefore a natural indicator of "creation order" in your collection. Unless you need the timestamp for other reasons of course.

Comment: what's the type of values stored in created?     Can you recreate this?  I tried with a simple mongo collection and the index sizes are same for ascending/descending

Comment: Background indexes do end up being larger than ones created in the foreground. Also, you shouldn't need to create both ascending and descending versions as the order doesn't matter for single-field indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is due to the ascending index being created in the foreground, and the descending index being created in the background.

From [the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/build-indexes-in-the-background/#considerations) on background index creation:

> Background index builds take longer to complete and result in an index
>   that is *initially* larger, or less compact, than an index built in the
>   foreground. Over time, the compactness of indexes built in the
>   background will approach foreground-built indexes.

So create your index in the foreground if you want it as compact as possible, but a background index will also become more compact over time.